# Scrapy yield request from one spider to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have the following code:

```
#FirstSpider.py
class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'first'
    start_urls = ['https://www.basesite.com']
    next_urls = []

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.css('bunch > of > css > here'):
        self.next_urls.append(url.css('more > css > here'))
        l = Loader(item=Item(), selector=url.css('more > css'))
        l.add_css('add', 'more > css')
        ...
        ...
        yield l.load_item()
        for url in self.next_urls:
            new_urls = self.start_urls[0] + url
            yield scrapy.Request(new_urls, callback=SecondSpider.parse_url)

#SecondSpider.py
class SecondSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'second'
    start_urls = ['https://www.basesite.com']


    def parse_url(self):
        """Parse team data."""
        return self
        # self is a HtmlResponse not a 'response' object


    def parse(self, response):
        """Parse all."""
        summary = self.parse_url(response)
        return summary

#ThirdSpider.py
class ThirdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # take links from second spider, continue:
```

I want to be able to pass the url scraped in Spider 1 to Spider 2 (in a different script).  I'm curious as to why when I do, the 'response' is a `HtmlResponse` and not a `response` object ( When doing something similar to a method in the same class as Spider 1; I don't have this issue )

What am i missing here? How do i just pass the original response(s) to the second spider? ( and from the second onto the third, etc..?)

Comment: Why not handle all in one spider and different method names and pass the request. Ideally your run one spider per crawl, So that means you need to either output results from spider1 at some place and then input them to spider 2

Comment: Right.  I had a similar approach before but ultimately I wanted to separate it into two spiders ( since theres a lot going on from two page sources and they will be added to two seperate databases later ) and was hoping to accomplish this by serving the requests from spider 1 to 2 w/o having spider 1 write the urls to a file..

Answer (score 1):

You could use Redis as shared resource between all spiders https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-redis

- Run all N spiders (don't close on idle state), so each of them will be connected to same Redis and waiting tasks(url, request headers) from there;
- As the side-effect push task data to Redis from X_spider with specific key (Y_spider name).

Answer (score 0):

What about using inheritance? "parse" function names should be different.
If your first spider inherits from the second, it will be able to set the callback to self.parse_function_spider2